# How to use getString() on static?

Tags: java, android, string

I am using different text files in assets folder (arabic.txt ,english.txt)
and i want to change the file base in device language

Is it passable to set file name in values/string file ?

```
public static class TipsSource{
    // if language arabic select file arabic.txt
    // if language english select file english.txt
    public static String English="english.txt";

}
```

string file

```
<string name="LangFile">"english.txt"</string>
```

i tried

```
    public static String English=getResources().getString(R.string.LangFile);
```

and

```
   public static String English= getString(R.string.LangFile);
```

and

```
   public static String English= R.string.LangFile;
```

> Update "solved"

I created 
assets/en/file.txt
assets/ar/file.txt

TxtFile = file.txt

```
            reader = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open((context.getString(R.string.tips) + TxtFile))));
```

string file

```
<string name="langdir">en/</string>
```

Comment: So the first one does not work?

Comment: no @karandhillon

Answer (score 0):

May be the quotes are redundant.

```
<string name="LangFile">english.txt</string>
```

You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

it can't，because static can't get the context，getResources() must need context

Comment: please check the update and see if you can help me with it

Answer (score 0):

`getClass()` method can't use in static method. so I made like this.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

public class ResourceTest {
    public static String EnglishTextFile = "english.txt";
    public static String ArabicTextFile = "arabic.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String textLanguage = "";

        // case 1 : load value from arguments of main method.
        textLanguage = args[0];

        // case 2: just wrote what you want.
        textLanguage = EnglishTextFile;

        ResourceTest resourceTest = new ResourceTest();

        resourceTest.readTextFile(textLanguage);
    }

    public File readTextFile(String fileName) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

        URL resource = classLoader.getResource(fileName);
        if (resource != null) {
            return new File(resource.getFile());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not found file. File name is '" + fileName + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For localization purpose, I would use `/res` folder rather than `/assets`.
You can place those text files in `/res/raw` for your default language (Arabic) and `/res/raw-en` for translated in English. (Note that you must use same file name)

```
/res/raw/file.txt
/res/raw-en/file.text
```

By that way, you don't have to care resource switching between the languages. That will be Android OS's business.

```
InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.file);
```

Answer (score 0):

nothing works with my app res/raw folder also

so i did like this 
assets/ar/file.txt

TxtFile = file.txt

```
            reader = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open((context.getString(R.string.langdir) + TxtFile))));
```

string file

```
<string name="langdir">en/</string>
```